# Hosting files on apache server

Tags: apache

I installed apache2 on Ubuntu. I tested the installation,able to see default page on browser.

I created directory inside /var/www/html . I copied file there,  which I want to access from my m/c's IP. But I am not able to see my directory in browser only see default page. I haven't done anything with apache earlier, so please ignore the naiveness.

I additionally did this:
sudo adduser username www-data
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
sudo chmod -R g+rwX /var/www

Comment: You have a directoryindex which overrides the showing of the new directory you created.   Remove or rename the index.html in /var/www/html and you should see the directory

Comment: Thnx @Doon it works. I need to allow this directory access for certain IP's only, how can I do that? Can u point to a specific doc, which guides me from beginner to advance level configuration ?

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/auth.html The docs should help.